# Android app in Scala http request

Tags: android, scala, http, get

I'm trying to make Android application using Scala. It should make a GET request. I saw some Java code which implements this functionality but this did not help me much. So, can some one explain me how to do it or maybe give a code example?
For now I have:

```
protected override def onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val intent: Intent = getIntent()
    val massage: String = makeJson(intent.getExtras())
    val url:String = """http://something.I.dont.want.to.show?info=""" + URLEncoder.encode(massage, "utf-8")
    val req = new MyAsyncTask()
    req.execute(url)
    val data:JSONArray = req.get()

    // Create the text view
    val textView:TextView = new TextView(this)
    textView.setTextSize(40)
    textView.setText(data.toString())

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView)
}
```

And MyNewTask class:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask[String, Void, JSONArray] {


override protected def doInBackground(arg0: String*): JSONArray = {
    val httpclient: HttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient()
    try {
        val response: HttpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(arg0(0)))
        val statusLine: StatusLine = response.getStatusLine()
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            val out:ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out)
            out.close()
            val responseString = out.toString()
            new JSONArray(responseString)
            }
        else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close()
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase())
                null
            }
        }
    catch {
      case e: ClientProtocolException => {new JSONArray()}
      case ioe: IOException => {new JSONArray()}
    }
}
```

}

Log:

```
03-30 20:25:34.105: D/dalvikvm(30197): --- called into dvmAbstractMethodStub
03-30 20:25:34.105: D/AndroidRuntime(30197): Shutting down VM
03-30 20:25:34.105: W/dalvikvm(30197): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419d6930)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myscalaandroidapp2/com.example.myscalaandroidapp2.DisplayMassageActivity}: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197): Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:160)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:482)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at com.example.myscalaandroidapp2.DisplayMassageActivity.onCreate(DisplayMassageActivity.scala:60)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    ... 11 more
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197): Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.os.AsyncTask.doInBackground(AsyncTask.java)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-30 20:25:34.110: E/AndroidRuntime(30197):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-30 20:25:34.115: W/dalvikvm(30197): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419d6930)
03-30 20:25:34.115: I/Process(30197): Sending signal. PID: 30197 SIG: 9
```

If i understand right it fails with starting a AsyncTask or something like that.
Code is very lame, probably. And because of it I did not ask how to fix it, but ask how to to do it from the beginning. But if you see where the error is, I will glad to hear it.

Comment: This site is for helping users solve specific issues with their code - how can you accomplish what you're asking? There are probably 100 ways to do it. The point is you need to show some effort instead of expecting people to do your work for you. Notice the -7 your question received? That's a good indicator that you need to do some digging and come back with a question that meets these guidelines:

http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

You get downvotes without any comments because members get tired of seeing this again and again.

Comment: @SQLiteNoob Is that better?

Comment: YES!! Now the community has something to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first bet is that because the above code doesn't reference MyAsyncTask's `doInBackground` method directly, Progruard removes it.

Try addign the following to your proguard configuration file:

```
-keep class * extends android.os.AsyncTask {
  *;
}
```

**Edit:**

I would actually consider using Futures if you are already using Scala for Android. Also if you do most of your code in Scala I can recommend the [Scaloid library](https://github.com/pocorall/scaloid) too.

Comment: Yes, you totally right. And thanks for your advise about Futures and Scaloid library. I did not try is yet, because  I need to finish the app as fast as I can, but I really appreciate your help.